# Meteor server side ajax

Tags: ajax, meteor

I'm trying to access a remote server API and need to make an ajax call. It's best if it's done from the server side so as not to compromise the API keys. How would I do this with meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a rest API, you probably want to use `Meteor.http.post` (docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_post)). Something like:

```
Meteor.http.post(API_URL, {foo: 'bar', other: 'data'}, function(err, result) {
  if (!err)
    // do something with the result.
});
```

This works client side too.

Answer (score 3):

The current way seems to be via the [http](http://docs.meteor.com/#http) package.

First add it to your project like so: `meteor add http`. Then you can use it like this:

```
var result = HTTP.call("GET", "http://api.twitter.com/xyz",
  {params: {user: userId}});
```